# Does Redis-py support unicode and utf-8 and how does it work

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, redis

I'm new to redis and i was wondering if redis-py supports unicode and utf-8.
I guess we can also encode and decode, but i'm not sure how.
Let's say i enter a value into redis like this: 'ü'.
Then i'll get this output: '\xc3\xbc'

Could someone explain me this process

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redis (the datastore) stores bytes, not unicode.

In the python redis module, constructors `redis.Redis` and `redis.StrictRedis` have a `encoding` parameter, which defaults to `utf-8`.

So your 'ü' is being encoded in utf-8 before it is stored in redis. When you retrieve it later in python, you just get the encoded bytes.

```
>>> print(b'\xc3\xbc'.decode('utf-8'))
ü
```

Answer (score 2):

`redis.connection.Encoder` has an option of setting `decode_responses` to `True`. Depending on how you are setting up the connections it could be a pass-through arg. E.g. in our case we are using the ConnectionPool and the following does the job:

```
  client = Redis.from_url(..., decode_responses=True, ...)
```